# Angular reusable add and edit component

Tags: angular

What is the cleaner solution to handle add/edit objects.

**Option 1**

- Component for Add
- Component for Edit

**Option 2**

- resusable component `ObjectForm`
- Two components `AddObject` and `EditObject`. Both reuse `ObjectForm`
- reusable component uses `IsNew` boolean to check if `object` input is not null.

Any other Options ?

Comment: is `object` returned by any API or has a unique identifier like `id` which would not exist in a new `object` created by user but only during edit ? If so you can just do with one component.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's good to avoid if statement especially for this use case.

For me it's a kind of option 2:

Use case 1: create a new item :

- CreateItemComponent extends ItemForm

Use case 2: update an item:

- EditItemComponent extends ItemForm
- EditItemComponent has `@Input() item`

In your ItemForm, you have methods which are common to CreateItemComponent and EditItemComponent.

And in each component you have specific methods for the component.

Maybe, it's not necessary to have a flag `isNew`. The objects will be very similar the first (create) doesn't have default values and the edited object has the values of the item which is editing.

But finally, they have same properties. If you have an ID you can use a UUID to simulate this during the creation.

**For further**

I do another layer for the actions of my form. I have:

- CreateItemComponent -> ItemActions -> ItemForm
- EditItemComponent -> ItemActions -> ItemForm

Here I decoupled the actions (because they are identical) and I don't have duplicate code in Create and Edit component